# How to make a Log that links to a specific line in the source in Intellij IDEAS / Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

So when an error occurred during runtime, the log always show a link to the specific error and you can click on it to be taken there directly.

I'm looking to exploit this function for my own use (since finding where the log is generated across multiple files can be a pain). Of course you can just put the source in the log key but if I'm able to link it just the way Android Studio / Intellij IDEAS does it with the error output, that would be MASSIVELY helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Seems that you need to get IntlliJ's src code and add your log-linking function by copying the origin ERROR log code. Good luck!

Comment: @herbertD Holy moly of ouch. I was hoping if anyone knows a plugin or maybe some other solutions since it seems _far too useful to not be included_ (or hidden) somewhere in the IDE.

Comment: OK, I've post a work around below. @Log Ampere

Answer (score 2):

The following code will be a work-around to print the logged function name and line number (in Java):

```
private static String _FUNC_() {
    int STACK_LEVEL = 2;
    StackTraceElement traceElement = ((new Exception()).getStackTrace())[STACK_LEVEL];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<");
    String className = traceElement.getClassName();
    className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    sb.append(className);
    sb.append(":");
    sb.append(traceElement.getMethodName());
    sb.append(":");
    sb.append(traceElement.getLineNumber());
    sb.append("> ");
    return sb.toString();
}
```